# ¿Cómo acceder a un archivo en raw fuera de una Activity en Android? Da error NotFoundException

Tags: android

Tengo unos archivos en la carpeta `res/raw` de mi aplicación [android](/questions/tagged/android).

Cuando estoy en una Activity puede acceder a cualquiera de esos archivos sin problemas con este código:

```
    try {
        InputStream in_s = getResources().openRawResource(rawId);
        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        String t = new String(b);
        mTextView.setText(t);
        in_s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mTextView.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Pero si intento acceder al archivo desde fuera de la Activity no puedo:

```
   try {
        InputStream in_s = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.invitatorio_1);
        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        t = new String(b);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        t="Test";
    }
```

Me da un error del tipo `NotFoundException`. Esta es parte de la traza del error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: org.midominio.app, PID: 26161
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f100001
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1313)
>           at android.content.res.MiuiResources.openRawResource(MiuiResources.java:226)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1205)
>           at org.midominio.app.model.Invitatorio.getTexto(Invitatorio.java:38)

El archivo existe, la única diferencia es que intento obtenerlo desde fuera de una Activity, en una clase normal.

Comment: esta clase no usa el contexto?

Comment: Hola creo que es porque la librería ´Resources.getSystem´ es distinta. 
De hecho es comprobable si en la clase pasas por parámetros el contexto de la actividad y usas el código ´context.getResources().openRawResource(rawId);´ debería de funcionar. Imagino que lo que no quieres hacer es pasar por parámetro el contexto

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez no, es una clase que pertenece al modelo. Ella obtiene contenido del modelo de datos mediante varios métodos. Los datos son traídos de Firebase, pero, para ahorrar consumo en Firebase he optado por poner en unos archivos cierto contenido que es grande y que se repite mucho en la App. Aquí desde el modelo intento obtener esa información de uno de los archivos.

Comment: @GustavoMora sí, quisiera evitar tener que pasar el contexto. Esa clase pertenece al modelo, el cual me trae los datos desde Firebase, pero para evitar consumir muchos recursos decidí poner en archivos (dentro de la app) algún contenido que es jugoso, poco actualizable y repetitivo, así no tengo que estarlo trayendo de Firebase y consumiendo recursos. No quiero reflejar bajo ningún concepto algo relativo al contexto en el modelo de datos.

Comment: Estoy sumamente interesado en conocer que harás, creo que necesitas el contexto definitivamente, opino que podrías por ejemplo hacer un ´interface´ que se implemente en la Actividad y pasarlo por el constructor a la clase de esta manera mantienes la separación de dependencias pero igual es sólo una sugerencia. Revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855725/4775484) en so en inglés

Comment: has intentado declarar... private Activity activity;  y luego: activity.getResources.....//// , algo así, no se me entiendes la idea, @GustavoMora también dice algo interesante, que implementes un contexto por medio de una interface.

Comment: @A.Cedano el error "NotFoundException" puede deberse a permisos, confirma si tienes WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: @GustavoMora he encontrado una solución basada en `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ruta)` (ver respuesta dada al respecto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice @Elenasys en su respuesta, era un problema del `Contexto`.

Una posible solución sería en efecto pasar el contexto a la clase, sea por medio del constructor, sea por medio de un *setter*. En este caso, si se optase por esa opción, sería mejor hacerlo con un *setter*, dado que la instancia de la clase se crea desde un snapshot de Firebase directamente.

Otra opción sería mediante: `.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ruta)`, por ejemplo:

```
String filePath = "res/raw/invitatorio_1.txt";
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
```

Me parece una solución más simple y más conforme al modelo de datos, pues nos evitaría tener que declarar un miembro del tipo `Context` en la clase.

**P.D:**

Como dije en comentarios en la pregunta. El sentido de acceder a este archivo desde un elemento del modelo de datos es ahorrar consumo de recursos en el contexto de Firebase. Hay en la App contenido más o menos largo, pero que se repite con frecuencia. Para evitar consumo de cantidad de datos en Firebase se ha optado por poner ese contenido de forma local en la App.

Answer (score 3):

En este caso puedes usar el método [getResources().openRawResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(int)), pero para esto es importante tener el contexto, el cual podrías enviar en el constructor de tu clase:

```
 InputStream in_s = contexto.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.invitatorio_1);
```

de esta forma podrás obtener sin problema el `InputStream`.

Comment: Es correcto, era un problema del contexto, he probado a poner el contexto en el ámbito de la clase (mediante un *setter*)  y funciona. Aunque he optado por otra solución que, a mi juicio, es mejor para este caso (ver respuesta). Gracias de todos modos.